# How to get a output response as integer from a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the following response from a stored procedure to authenticate the user and read a response from stored procedure based on the user input.

```
CREATE Procedure sp_UserAuthentication
@UserName varchar(20),
@UserPassword varchar(20),
@Resp int output
AS
DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @IsAdmin bit;
DECLARE @IsActive bit;
Select @Count = COUNT(UserName) from tbl_UserDetails where UserName = @UserName and UserPassword = @UserPassword
IF @Count = 1
BEGIN


Select @IsActive = IsActive, @IsAdmin = @IsAdmin from tbl_UserDetails where UserName = @UserName and UserPassword = @UserPassword
IF @IsActive = 0 -- InActive user
BEGIN
    SET @Resp = 3
END
ELSE IF @IsAdmin = 1 -- Admin user
BEGIN
    SET @Resp = 2
END
ELSE -- Normal user
BEGIN
    SET @Resp = 1
END
END
ELSE -- InValid user
BEGIN 
   SET @Resp = 0
END

GO
```

I'm getting response as always 1 for a valid user and 0 for invalid user. I'm not getting the response as 2 for admin and 3 for an inactive user.

```
DECLARE @Res int 
exec sp_UserAuthentication 'user', 'pwd', @Res out
SELECT @Res
```

Table:

```
Create Table tbl_UserDetails(
UserName Varchar(20) primary key,
UserPassword Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
IsAdmin Bit Default 0,
IsActive Bit Default 1
);
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you have a couple of issues here. First is the sp_ prefix. This is a bad naming convention. You would be better off using a different or even better, no prefix at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix The other issue is one that is more serious. You are storing passwords in clear text. Passwords should ALWAYS be salted and hashed.

Comment: As for your actual question, we can't really offer much help here because we have no data to work with. Do you have users that are inactive? I think you could leverage a case expression in your select statement and avoid all that complicated If/Else logic to check your variables.

Comment: show us some sample data, it seems to work for me

Comment: Instead of building your own authentication use your framework's built-in mechanisms. What you posted stores *clear passwords* which is unacceptable these days. You can't have missed the dozens of breaches in the past year! You need to store and compare salted hashes. Cryptographically strong hashes require *thousands* of iterations. ASP.NET already contains a strong authentication mechanism, which can also be used by desktop applications. Use that

Comment: Thanks guys, ill make sure to use password as salted and hashed

Comment: Typo in your second `select`: `@IsAdmin = @IsAdmin`. Tips: Use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT` when you are only checking for existence and don't need a precise count. A single `select` will return the results, if any. You can use `@@RowCount` to check if a matching user row was found, hence the count/exists check isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind everybody's stern reprimands about storing clear text passwords. You desperately need to read about and understand how to encrypt these. But your entire procedure could be greatly simplified to something like this.

```
CREATE Procedure UserAuthentication
(
    @UserName varchar(20),
    @UserPassword varchar(20),
    @Resp int output
)
AS
    set @Resp = 0 --This sets the response to invalid unless we actually find a user

    Select @Resp = 
        case when IsActive = 0 then 3 --Inactive User
            when IsAdmin = 1 then 2 --Admin user
            else 1 --Normal user
        end
    from tbl_UserDetails 
    where UserName = @UserName 
        and UserPassword = @UserPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore that you're putting usernames and passwords into a table.  Please don't do that, and if you do, please use some kind of encryption/hashing.  But look in your SELECT statement in the middle:

```
Select @IsAdmin = @IsAdmin
```

You are setting @IsAdmin to @IsAdmin, you need to set that to just IsAdmin.

Comment: The OP could also return the row and check fields on the client side, and use a Join instead of two separate queries.